# How to create a database on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: database, ibm-cloud

I have created an application on Bluemix. I need to copy my database on Bluemix that can be accessed from my adapter. Can anyone give me detailed steps on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

First thing: if your database is reachable through the Internet and you only need to connect to it from the application, please note that a cf application on Bluemix can access the public network and so it is already able to connect to your DB in this scenario.

Assuming that you have a requirement for migrating the DB on Bluemix, you didn't specify which kind of database you want to migrate, here are the main (not all) possibilities you currently have:

RDBMS:

- [PostgreSQL by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/postgresql-by-compose/) (you need an account on compose.io)
- [SQL Database](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/sql-database/) (DB2, only Premium plan available)
- [ClearDB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cleardb-mysql-database/) (MySQL)
- [ElephantSQL](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/elephantsql/) (this is basically a PostgreSQL as a Service - that is you have to work on the db via API)
- you could use the RDBS capability of [dashDB](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dashdb/)

No-SQL:

- [Cloudant](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db/) (documental)
- [Redis by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/redis-by-compose/) (ultra fast key-value db. You need an account on compose.io)
- [MongoDB by Compose](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/redis-by-compose/) (you need an account on compose.io)
- [IBM Graph](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-graph/) (graph No-SQL db)

I suggest you to take a look at the Bluemix Catalog (subcategory Data and Analytics) and to refer to the Docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dashDB service on your bluemix, and copy / upload your data to Bluemix dashDB database, using dashDB VCAP Credentials to connect to it from your adapter, or you can bind your dashDB service to you application on Bluemix.